# R aggregate data by defining grouping

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping, aggregate

I am having trouble grouping and summing the follwing data in R:

```
category freq
1    C1     9
2    C2    39
3    C3     3
4    A1    38
5    A2     2
6    A3    29
7    B1   377
8    B2   214
9    B3   790
10   B4   724
11   D1   551
12   D2   985
13   E5    19
14   E4    28
```

to look like this:

```
category freq
1    A    69
2    B    2105
3    C    51
4    D    1536
5    E    47
```

I usually use ddply to aggregate data by an attribute but this just adds all values rows with the same attribute in a given column. I need to be able to specify multiple attributes that should be lumped into one category.

Comment: Please take a look at my modified answer. I have included a full example, as well as what the output would look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you add a column to your dataframe, that would be the letter part of your "Category" column. Then, you could use `ddply`.

Example:

```
 df = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5), category = c("AB1", "AB2", "B1", "B2", "B3"), freq = c(50,51,2,26))
 df$new = as.factor(gsub("\\d", "", df$category))
```

You could then use `ddply` based on the new column, as follows:

```
 library(plyr)
 aggregate <- ddply(df, .(new), summarize, freq = sum(freq))
```

You get the following result:

```
#  new freq
#1  AB  101
#2   B   31
```

This would work only if **you intend to group all the categories with similar "alphabetical" substring under the same umbrella category**.

If, HOWEVER, you wish to group **custom categories** under one category, (your example: KG, XM and L4 would be part of the same category), you could define new "super" categories, and assign each sub-category to the appropriate "super" category. One way that I can think of is the `switch` function. Please see example below:

```
 df = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5), category = c("A", "B", "KG", "XM", "L4"), freq = c(50,51,3,2,26))

 fct <- function(cat) {switch(cat, "A" = "CAT1", "B" = "CAT2", "KG" = "CAT3", "XM" = "CAT3", "L4"="CAT3")}
 df$new = as.factor(unlist(lapply(df$category, fct)))

 aggregate <- ddply(df, .(new), summarize, freq = sum(freq))
```

This will give you:

```
 #   new freq
 #1 CAT1   50
 #2 CAT2   51
 #3 CAT3   31
```

Comment: The data I listed was just an example but I will actually need to define cases where something like KG, XM, and L4 will be aggregated into one category.

Comment: Not a problem. Let me modify my answer accordingly and get back to you.

Comment: @Rick Please check my modified answer. I have replaced the `substr` function by `gsub`, which would extract the "alphabetical" portion of the column, no matter what the length of each category's name is.

Comment: @Rick I just realized that you wish to customize your categories, beyond a classification based on similar "alphabetical" portions of the categories' names. I have included one possible way of achieving what you are looking for. Please take a look at my edited answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Again, this is a very simplified way of doing this. If you could provide a detailed description of how many subcategories and "super" categories you have, I could help you find a more efficient way of getting the result you want.

Comment: Worked perfectly!! Thank you so much.