# How many categorical variable of each factor?

Tags: r, dataframe, categorical-data

I would like to know how many different species each familly has?
Anyone can provide me this code? I am not very familliar with R.

### Example Data

[image]

Comment: i dont want totals of species, but how many levels of species

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366387/r-aggregate-data-by-defining-grouping but hard to know

Answer (score -1):

You have angered us!

For your learning, and the sake of our sanity. please read the rules of stackoverflow before posting. Now for the answer. I googled and got this SO answer:
[How to count the number of unique values by group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28173677/how-to-count-the-number-of-unique-values-by-group)

applying it to your data, first I need to create your data because you have given us an image (not helpful):

```
week <- c(sample(1:40, size = 20))
family <- c(sample(rep(c("Acrocephalidae", "Sylviidae", "Muscicapidae"), 40), size = 20))
species <- c(sample(rep(c("Acrocephalidae Schoenobaenus", "Sylvia communis", "Erithacus rubetra", "Cettia cetti"), 40), size = 20))           
recapture <- c(sample(rep(0:1, 40), 20))
dat <- data.frame(week, family, species, recapture)
```

This just randomly generates similar data to yours. Now we can answer your question:

```
library(dplyr) #this uses the dplyr package. install first to use
dat %>% group_by(family) %>% summarise(count = n_distinct(species))
```

Next time please read the rules, do some googling and if you have no idea about a language... do more googling.

Good luck!